# How to define operation on dataframe and run them later?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to define a set of aggregates and operations on a dataframe on different stages but I don't want them to be executed (just defined) and then execute them later (like a pipeline)
If you are familiar with Frameless (I don't want to use Frameless), something like Job[A].

```scala
def addSelect(df:Dataframe) = {
    df.select("name")
}

def addCount(df:Dataframe) = {
    df.count()
}

def addSum(df:Dataframe) = {
    df.sum()
}

def addShow(df:Dataframe) = {
    df.show()
}

val df = ...
val pipeline = addSum( addSelect(df) )
//if(userWantsToExecute) pipeline.execute()
```

Comment: You can make those steps **functions** _(instead of **methods**)_, then compose them using `andThen`, and finally you will run the pipeline passing the `df` as input.

Comment: There are two types of operations on `DataFrame`, first are `transformers` like `select` etc others are `consumers/actions` like `show`, `collect` etc. All the transformers are lazy, which means they just add a transformer operation to the executionPlan but don't actually execute anything. Execution is done whenever you add a consumer such as `show`, `collect` etc.

Comment: If you look into the docs - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, everything classified as `Actions` are the ones which do the execution.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I understand that actions are not lazy, that's why I used some of them here in this example. I want everything to be just the definition and get run them after.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own **Pipeline** like this:

```
final class Pipeline[A] private (val run: () => A) extends AnyVal {  
  final def compose[B](f: A => B): Pipeline[B] =
    new Pipeline(() => f(this.run()))
}

object Pipeline {
  def start[A](input: => A): Pipeline[A] =
    new Pipeline(() => input)
}
```

This is basically the same I said in my comment, but this makes it easier to use.
For example:

```
val pipeline = Pipeline.start(input = df).compose(addSelect).compose(addSum)
pipeline.run()
```

---

Note: The above code is for general use, you can make it more specific to **DataFrames** if you want.

Comment: better if we rename the `compose` to `andThen` or something similar.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yeah, I would expect OP to rename everything to what he / she finds more readable. For example, I personally like `map` instead of `compose` & `andThen` _(as this is basically a mix between a **Reader** and a **IO**, but weaker)_, and I would just use `apply` instead of `start` or `create`.

Comment: The main question that makes it more specific about Dataframe is that if you get catalyst optimizations when you define it like that. Especially in the case that you have multiple "Execution" or aggregators?

Comment: @Omid yes, why not? As I said, this is basically the same as `addSum(addSelect(df))` just that the whole thing is made lazy and whit nicer syntax. But, this effectively the same as `() => addSum(df => addSelect(() => df()))` _(or something like that)_. - Additionally, the **catalyst** optimizations are completely _runtime_ - Thus. the comment you decide to run your pipeline,  everything will be exactly the same.